# cmake doesn't recognize CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION setting

Tags: eclipse, variables, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to generate an eclipse .project and .cproject from an existing cmake file.  Running cmake from the project root I tried adding to the root CMakeLists.txt
set(CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2) which apparently might do nothing as it is a local variable, not the global env variable, if i understand correctly.

Trying to add the flag to the commandline like this:

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2 .
```

Produces the following warning.  So how does one let cmake know the eclipse version?

-- Could not determine Eclipse version, assuming at least 3.6 (Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION if this is wrong.

I checked the .project file and it seems to be using cdt 4.  Pretty old.

kesten

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It would be really cool if there was a solution to this problem.

Comment: A workaround I found is making sure that eclipse is in your PATH so that CMake can find it. Then you won't have to specify the Eclipse version manually.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as accepted? It's more clear that it worked in case others read the question :)

Comment: I have the same problem and am waiting for the newest version. Does it affect the project or my work, if the eclipse version could not bet set correctly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem and after looking at CMake's code I noticed that the actual variable used to get the Eclipse's version is named _ECLIPSE_VERSION (starting with underscore) and not CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION. Here's what the code looks like:

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2 .
```

That worked for me!

**EDIT: Older versions of CMake don't recognise Eclipse 4.2** (which uses CDT 8.1) but does recognize 3.7 (which uses CDT 8.0). I used -D_ECLIPSE_VERSION=3.7 and Juno picked up well the project configuration (previously I had unresolved inclusions due to incompatibility of the CDT4 files generated by default). As pointed out by m3tikn0b, newer versions of CMake do recognize until Eclipse Kepler 4.3.

Comment: the cmake version I tested with today (2.8.12.1) supports -D_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2 and recognises it as "Juno"

Comment: Or add to CMakeLists.txt

`set(_ECLIPSE_VERSION "4.4")`

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in CMake. See [0014422: CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION is not taken into account](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14422). THe issue tracker says it will be corrected in cmake 2.8.13.

Comment: CMake jumped to version 3.0 directly so anyone interested on this should check that version.

Answer (score 2):

same problem here. After search i found the following solution:

previously tried:

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2  ../src
```

and it doesn't work. Then i tried:

```
cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2  ../src
```

This worked for me.. I hope it helps.